# Why is the net speed of Stack Overflow so fast?

Tags: discussion

This question is about the net speed.

I'm from China, and I find that opening pages on Stack Overflow is *very* fast, normally within a range of 1 to 4 seconds. This speed is very good for a website outside China; it's even faster than some native websites.

Not every website outside China has such good speed, so I am wondering why and how Stack Overflow manages to be so quick.

Comment: Badge speed slow is. Yes, mmm. (Yoda)

Comment: +1 very good question. Thumbs up to the team - recently I tried to access SO via a 64 kbit per second connection and it was quite smooth - not as smooth as via a fast connection, but still very very usable.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Because the developers care about optimizing these things.** They recognize that performance (speed) is a feature, and an important one at that. It's all about the details, the same reason why Google is famously fast.

For example, they [worry about the size of the code that the client must download](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103639/remove-ies-compatibility-mode-button-from-se-sites), even going so far as to compress aspects where the compression has a demonstrated benefit on download speed (but also [carefully benchmarking to get the most bang for the buck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100428/why-dont-you-get-rid-of-your-newlines-and-spaces-minifi-your-pages/100436#100436)). And they [constantly evaluate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/help-us-test-the-advantages-of-using-a-cdn) better [content delivery systems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90921/help-us-test-cdns-round-2) and [switch providers to attain the maximum performance possible for all users](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/the-speed-of-light-sucks/). And, of course, a [well-designed and well-implemented design/stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370) is vital as well, along with taking care to hire smart programmers and provide them with the right tools to do their job as effectively as possible.

See also: [A day in the life of a slow page at Stack Overflow](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/05/02/A+day+in+the+life+of+a+slow+page+at+Stack+Overflow) posted on one of the developer's blogs.
See what I mean?

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is the primary advantage of using a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) or *CDN* solution:

Note this question: [Help us test the advantages of using a CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/help-us-test-the-advantages-of-using-a-cdn)