# What is stackoverflow webhost

Tags: support, stack-overflow, web-hosting

Just wanted to know what company does SO gets its hosting services from. The site is very responsive and fast. I would like to get my hosting done in the same place. Thanks

Comment: Usually companies this big have their own servers, wouldn't you say?

Comment: AFAIK they're renting their own server racks in several data centers, but the speed of the site is down to much more important factors than the hosting location. It's in the whole thing's architecture and design - and a team that is obsessively working on optimizing both all the time.

Answer (score 7):

Their host is [PEER 1](http://www.peer1.com/stackoverflow), visible on the footer of every page:

[image]

But [it's not just the hosting service that makes Stack Overflow fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103995/why-is-the-net-speed-of-stack-overflow-so-fast/103997#103997). That's a *feature* to the developers, and they work hard to ensure that the site is responsive.

Also see the canonical [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: omg..I cant believe I missed that