# Is the data downloaded by the app compressed?

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app

I've installed the android app, because well *reasons*, and through I have a somewhat inexpensive data plan (I normally have enough for a month), that doesn't mean that I leave it without control. So through it is elsewhere that the API sends gzipped data, I couldn't find anything about the iOS nor Android app.

Comment: reasons = hats? :D

Comment: Just a fun fact: This page (just the HTML) has a wire(less) size of 16.51KB (desktop) and 8.41KB (mobile web).  The API response with iOS filters is 1.75KB.  There are other factors like the web having more resources to load or the app getting higher res images but the API requests are very light.

Comment: Your Android should have the ability to report data usage per app (if it doesn't, load a decent ROM!). This makes it really easy to check if the apps you use are consuming a respectable about of data. My observation is the SE app uses minuscule amounts of data for my normal activity level (like an order of magnitude  less than if I do the  same things surfing SE sites using the mobile website).

Comment: Do desktops also receive data compressed?

Comment: @sunk818 [I remember that yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103997/213575)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, data downloaded from our API is compressed. As pointed out in the API docs [on compression](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression):

> During normal operation, we guarantee that all responses are compressed, either with GZIP or DEFLATE.

However, although many image assets that are downloaded by the app (e.g. site icons) are not compressed, they are cached on the device.

Comment: It's worth noting that images are not compressed because there is no savings over the formats' native compression. (zlib for PNG files).  That's standard across the web.

Comment: Arie and @Brian are all images cached, including avatars? This can explain the [excessive storage usage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290513/ios-app-storage-usage-excessive), right?