# iOS app storage usage excessive?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

On my iPad, the StackExchange app is using over half a Gigabyte.  Really? Is that necessary? Can we have an option to flush cached data?

I tried the option to clear the cache (in the Settings app, as suggested by @JAL in his/her answer). On the next app launch it sat at a dark blue, empty screen for about 20 seconds then quit. At the next launch it came up, but the storage usage went down by only 2%, from 653MB to 640MB.

I even tried a force reboot after that (hold `power`/`home` until `poweroff->AppleLogo->poweroff`) but that had no effect.

[image: App Settings]

Comment: No idea what would have gotten the storage that high or why clearing the cache didn't help.  I'll audit the cache clearing functions to see if I missed anything.

Comment: @BrianNickel This has been a problem for quite a while.  A couple of months ago I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, and that reduced the size significantly, but I forget what the baseline size was.  I'll try that again later today and post the results.

Comment: I had similar storage (~630MB) and clearing the cache instantly brought it down to ~50MB

Comment: Hmmmm... i just tried clearing the cache on my iphone and when I relaunched it did not auto close the first time. I suspect it actually crashed on my ipad.  I'll retry clearing the ipad cache later today.

Comment: @BrianNickel Seems like the crash prevented clearing the cache the first time (see my last comment on JAL's answer).  Is any diagnostic info recorded for an app crash that you would like to receive?

Comment: Mine had got to over 500 Mb, I deleted the app and downloaded it again and it's under 50 Mb now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already an option to clear the local cache in the Stack Exchange app-specific settings:

[image: Settings]

Just terminate the app from multitasking and launch it again for the setting to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this. See my update to the question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be something that is managed automatically by the app?  640MB seems a bit... excessive, even for a cache.

Comment: I was never able to get the iOS app documents and data that high, it always stayed under 200 mb for me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You would be surprised.  Many third party libraries have their own caches with high limits.  Integrate with a few dependencies that have 200+ mb caches, it adds up.  Note that I'm not defending the large size, but storage is cheap.

Comment: Not on a iPad, it isn't.  I could store nearly a hundred e-books in that same space.  Or nearly as many songs.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I don't think this post deserves a downvote.

Comment: @ExUmbris It's clear that someone did not find my answer useful.  I'll keep it around for another day or so but if the community does not feel like it adds value I might as well just delete it...

Comment: Here's a pity upvote, merry philosophically incorrect Christmas!

Comment: My storage was up to ~630MB, clearing the cache brought it down to ~50MB (I agree there should be some auto-management of this, storage on iDevices isn't cheap and I'm in a constant never ending battle to free up space!)

Comment: This is the correct answer after all.  It appears when I tried this solution originally, the app crashed during the launch where it should have cleared the cache.   Retrying the cache clearing was successful the second time, and reduced storage to 50MB.

Comment: @ExUmbris so glad to hear it!